# is there a parser generator capable of generating a parser that can parse this: S → 'x' S 'x' | 'x'

Tags: parsing, antlr, generator

For a while now I am intrigued by the fact that ANTLR isn't capable of parsing the following context free grammar rule:  S → 'x' S 'x' | 'x'.

It didn't seem that complex to me.

For all I know, ANTLR is the most powerful LL parser available.
Are there any other kind of parser generators (LR or other) that are capable of generating a parser for this?

gr,

Coen

Comment: yacc as well gives `conflicts: 1 shift/reduce`.

Comment: I have a regular expression that parses this: `x+` (Edit: D'oh! @Christopher is right, it must be `x(?:xx)*`).

Comment: @delnan: The number of `x` must be odd. Try `x(xx)*` instead.

Comment: Do you care about the set of strings generated by the grammar, or about the actual tree structure?  If you only care about the strings, then you can use a string-equivalent grammar, such as the one suggested by Christopher Creutzig.  If you care about the tree structure, you'll need to use a more advanced parser, such as a CFG (context free grammar) parser.  Unfortunately, such parsers are slower (asymptotically) than simple LL, LR, and LALR parsers.

Comment: @edward: Yes, the tree structure is important. So if I need to use a CFG parser, is it possible to generate one with a parser generator? and if yes, which parser generator. The difference in speed of the parser is not really significant when parsing source code IMHO.

Comment: This is pure speculation, but something tells me that a GLR parser could parse that... Hmm...

Comment: @Adam has this right, but it might be pretty expensive if there a lot of X tokens in a row.

Comment: @Edward: source code parsing speed matters if you are going to process a lot of text, and/or your parser may have a hard time with patches of the text.  A GLR parser can parse this grammar, but it might take a long time, as it has to track/resolve the (potential) ambiguities in the parse.  We had a similar problem trying to parse COBOL data declarations using GLR; it would take tens of minutes to get through a thousand declarations in a single file. (We found some ad hoc cures to remove the ambiguity and now our GLR-based COBOL parser is fast).  But if you process 1000 files...

Answer (score 5):

I don't think your grammar is LL(n) or LALR(n) or LR(n) for any n. Proof: Fix any n. Your input stream starts with n `x` characters, followed by another one. *At this point,* without any further look-ahead, do you need to go up or down?

Since the standard parser generators only work on languages in one of those classes (and many only for small values of n), it is not surprising that you don't find one that handles your input. You might want to reconsider if your grammar really needs to look the way it does; for the reduced example you gave, you could just as well have S → 'x' 'x' S | 'x', for example.

Comment: Excellent answer.  I'll add that, if you really *do* need to use the grammar listed (e.g. because you care about the tree structures that get generated), then you may need to use a context free grammar parser.  See <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar>

Comment: That's right, the grammar is not *(n). Basically that is what my question is about; are there parser generators that can handle those kind of grammars.

Answer (score 2):

In Antlr, you need to add a syntactic predicate to resolve the ambiguity, like this:

```
grammar fred;

sentence : ( 'x' 'x' 'x' ) => 'x' sentence 'x'
         |                    'x'
         ;
```

This shouldn't, I think, require more than 1 additional token of lookahead. The semantic predicate says "if you see an 'x' followed by another 'x', try the first alternative.

Antlr 3.3/Antlrworks 1.4.2 is happy with it:
[image]

Another option is to refactor your grammar to eliminate the alternative that introduces the ambiguity:

```
grammar fred;

start    : sentence
         ;

sentence : 'x'  'x'('x' 'x')*  'x'
         |      'x'
         ;
```

[image]

This, I believe, will give you the same parse tree (or close) as your original grammar.

Comment: but does it still parse "xxxxxxx"? As I understand it, it will go *down* too often.

Comment: I think it wants more lookahead. I just changed so it will only take the first alternative **if** that alternative can succeed. I think that will do it.

Comment: semantic predicates shouldn't be necessary at all, the grammar is unambiguous. I don't quite understand why ANTLR doesn't support it. is it too complex or is there another motivation?

Comment: The rule requires infinite lookahead. This cannot be parsed without backtracking as the correct alternatives cannot be determined until the end of the x tokens is reached. ANTLR will support it by enabling backtracking, which the predicate above does.

Comment: I would think that the rule doesn't require infinite lookahead, but rather unknown lookahead; the tokenstream is not infinite. Unknown lookahead is doable, so my question remains; why doesn't ANTLR support it.

Comment: Because the sentence rule has two equally valid alternatives. Yacc has a shift/reduce conflict and, by default, shifts (with a warning). Antlr has a first/follow conflict and, by default, disables the second alternative (with a warning). Refactoring your grammar to eliminate the alternative (see my answer above) should help.

Comment: they are not equally valid. This grammar is not ambiguous.

Comment: So you say. Good luck. Yacc/Bison and Antlr both appear to believe that it is.

Comment: x -> second alternative, x x -> invalid, x x x -> first alternative with nested second alternative, x x x x -> invalid

Comment: Hey, @NicholasCarey, could you tell which tool you used to draw the syntax diagram? :3

Comment: @PauloTorrens: Those diagrams come out of Antlr's debugger. http://antlr.org for Antlr; AntlrWorks is the debugger: http://tunnelvisionlabs.com/products/demo/antlrworks